# Is dysharmonia a recognized medical condition?

Tags: neurology, music, cognitive-science

In his book *Musicophilia*, Oliver Sacks discusses a case involving a woman named Rachel Y. who lost the ability to process harmony in a car accident. He then explains how this lead to [simultanagnosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultanagnosia). He terms this loss of harmony "dysharmonia."

Is dysharmonia a recognized medical condition? My google fu didn't yield anything besides his book.  If it is legit, are there any regions of the brain that when damaged induce dysharmonia?

Click [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=wuyZiwgsBdoC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=rachel+y+dysharmonia&source=bl&ots=hgU-zOVDhu&sig=lh4WxvwwkV2eAgtSh73aqfp6OIY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI-r-vjYyfxwIVRBU-Ch0Oogqt#v=onepage&q=rachel%20y%20dysharmonia&f=false) to read the case.

Comment: As you know, the standard on this site is that questions must be based on notable claims, not solely on your own curiosity. Is anyone claiming that "dysharmonia" is, or is not, a "recognized" condition (whatever that means)? Sacks does not seem to be making this claim.

Comment: Are you saying I am misinterpreting what he is saying? Is he then just using this term casually in a sort of descriptive manner to characterize the patients ailment?